# Reduce loops into one - TIPS ONLY

Tags: php, performance, loops, for-loop, reduce

Rewrite the code below so it would contain only one loop and only one
itterational variable would be used.

```
$result = Array();
for ($x = 0; $x < 6; $x++){
    for ($y = 0; $y < 6; $y++){
        for ($z = 0; $z < 6; $z++){
            $result[$x][$y][$z] = $x * $y * $z;
        }
    }
}
```

NO ANSWERS PLEASE, JUST POINT ME IN THE RIGHT DIRECTION. Is there a php class that can handle this? Or is it just a simple problem solving technique? Or is it a trick question?

Recommended result below:

```
$result = Array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 216; $i++){
    $x = $i % 6;
    $y = floor($i/6) % 6;
    $z = floor($i/36);
    $result[$x][$y][$z] = $x * $y * $z;
}
```

Comment: not homework. school is over...

Comment: why -3??? please explain why its a bad question...

Comment: @theB3RV because it shows no research effort or attempt to solve it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Missing the homework flag?

Think in base 6, and run a loop from zero to 6^3 (216) then use mod to reduce/shift back into `x y z` positions.

Comment: The homework flag is deprecated.

Comment: I was thinking of this route, but i feel like there is way too much computation for that. and its not homework. Job App.

Comment: @theB3RV way too computation? you're using a loop, so you'll only have to type the `mod` statements once. be thankful you get to let the loop do the rest!

Comment: A for loop has memory allocation, data shifting in and out of registers, and a comparison every iteration (compounded by multiple loops).  A MOD is a basic mathematical function applied to a single memory location (or likely in optimized code - a single register).  Now it depends on PHPs implementation, but mod could well be more efficient [not that your question even mentions optimizing]

Comment: See edited question for final solution. Thanks!

Comment: @theB3RV your final solution is incorrect... it has at least 2 errors.

Comment: its a meeting question

Answer (score 1):

Pro Tip #1: You can have multiple variable operations in a single for loop...

```
for($a = 0, $b = 10; $b > $a; $b++, $a--) {
    echo $a . $b;
}
```

Comment: You think I would be able to do the above 3 loops while only incrementing/decrementing one variable with that tip? I'll check it out.

Comment: If you got clever with it, absolutely. I can't give you the answer, remember? :-)